# create new user account manually on prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I am developing a module that get user data in a page , I wand to submit this data to prestashop database to create a new user account .
so how can I do this ?

how should I understand what data I should get from user Like email,phone number and etc . (I want to know this Shop get what data from user to sign them up).

thank you

Answer (score 2):

All the things you need are defined in the "classes/Customer.php" file.

Each PrestShop class has one "public static $definition" and each field of the $definition that has the "'required' => true", is required

Comment: thank for your answer Mahdi ;) so all information that on sign up page is token are same in definition by required true ?

Comment: Yes, you can just set required fields to register a customer and other fields are optional.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this piece of code to create a Customer.

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->firstname = 'John';
$customer->lastname = 'Doe';
$customer->email = 'johndoe@gmail.com';
$customer->passwd = md5(pSQL(_COOKIE_KEY_.'yoursecretpasswordhere'));
$customer->save();
```

Like Madhi said, you will get all information needed for the Customer in Customer.php

Cheers :)

Comment: thank you so much , how can I know witch data I should get from user to sign he/she up?Like first name last name , how can I get all parameters that is required?

Comment: You can get all attributes/informations in the Customer class in "classes/Customer.php". Check it and let me know.